# Complex conjugate of prime element generates the same prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R_K$ be ring of integers of imaginary quadratic field $K$.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R_K$.
Suppose $ \pi$ be prime element of $R_K$ which generates $P$.
Let $ \pi'$ be complex conjugate of $ \pi$.
Then how can I prove $ \pi'$ does not generate $P$ ?

Comment: In your example, $(\pi)$ and $(\pi')$ are *strictly* contained in $(5).$ Besides, if two elements generate the same ideal, they are multiple of eachother by some unit.

Comment: Sorry but did you try $\pi=3$ and $\pi= 1+i$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$? In an imaginary quadratic field there are only 3 cases for the factorization of a prime number: $(p)$ is prime (inert), $(p)=\mathfrak{p}^2$ (ramified), $(p)=\mathfrak{p}\overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ with $\mathfrak{p}\ne \overline{\mathfrak{p}}$ (split)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't since this may happen. First of all since the prime element could be real and hence fixed by complex conjugation. Even if you restrict to the case where $\pi$ can't be a real number this may still happen.

A good example is given in the comments. If you take the ideal $(1+i)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, the ring of gaussian integer, you can see that:

1. 1+i is a prime element by noting that its norm is 2.
2. its conjugate is 1-i=i(1+i) and i is a unit of the ring, so that these two elements generate the same ideal.

More generally speaking, a way to "get" to this example is simply starting a "proof" and where it goes wrong:
To generate the same ideal in a domain two elements must be the same up to a multiplication by a unit. In our case we would have that $\pi=u \pi'$ with $u$ a unit. By taking complex conjugate on both side we would then get that $\pi=|u| \pi$ where $|-|$ denotes the absolute value, which must then be equal to 1.

From here you can see that the choice of the example was rather natural, since the only elements in the ring with absolute value 1 are the four roots of unity.

**Remark**
I'm implicitly looking at the ring as embedded in the complex numbers, but at this level and for this problem I think this is not a priority issue.